# Passing object model as single object to an ArrayController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a starting page that requires a user enter an `apiKey`. With that form data, i pass that to my `deals` route, which then fetches the relevant data based on the entered `apiKey`.

My problem is that when i load the deal page directly with an `apiKey` in the URI, it works fine, however, when going from the form on the `start` page and submit with an `apiKey`, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed 'asdf'
```

Here is the app.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Deal = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Deal.FIXTURES = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Deal 1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Deal 2'}
]

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('start', { path: '/' });
  this.resource('deals', { path: '/deals/:api_key' });
});

App.StartController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  apiKey: '',
  getDeals: function (model) {
    this.transitionToRoute('deals', this.apiKey);
  }
});

App.DealsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // return App.Deal.getWonFor(params.api_key);
    return App.Deal.find();
  }
});

App.DealController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
});

App.DealsView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    // Add active class to first item
    this.$().find('.item').first().addClass('active');
    this.$().find('.carousel').carousel({interval: 1000});
  }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Won Deal Ticker</h2>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="start">
    {{view Em.TextField valueBinding="apiKey" placeholder="API Key" action="getDeals" }}
    <br />
    <button {{action 'getDeals' apiKey}} class="btn btn-large">Get Won Deals!</button>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="deals">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        {{#each model}}
          <div class="item">
            {{name}}
          </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Comment: did you post the same error message from the console? I don't see where "asdf" is coming from

Comment: Yup. The `start` view contains a TextField that I typed "asdf" as the `apiKey` and submitted using the button below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when you pass a second argument to `Route#transitionTo`, Ember.js assumes you're passing the model and sets it as the controller's model instead of using the `model` hook.

The problem is here:

```
this.transitionToRoute('deals', this.apiKey);
```

Now Ember.js believes that `this.apiKey` is the model for your route, and will skip calling the route's `model` hook and directly set what you passed as the controller's model.

I can think of 2 ways around this:

**Method 1 (preferred)**

You can create a new resource that wraps the `deals` resource:

```
this.resource('api', { path: '/:api_key' }, function() {
  this.resource('deals');
});
```

And then:

```
App.ApiRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return params.api_key;
  }
});

App.DealsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Deal.getWonFor(this.modelFor('api'));
  }
});
```

And:

```
getDeals: function () {
  this.transitionToRoute('deals', this.apiKey);
}
```

**Method 2**

This below is a quick workaround (probably not optimal), but should work:

```
getDeals: function () {
  var router = this.get('target'),
      url = '/deals/' + this.apiKey;

  Ember.run.once(function() {
    router.get('location').setURL(url);
    router.notifyPropertyChange('url');
  });

  this.router.router.handleURL(url);
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. I implemented "Method 1" and it worked great. I'm trying to wrap my head around why it worked. So due to the fact that we created a separated resource for the deals, that one can be an Array as expected and the Api resource and stay as the normal object resource?

Comment: Yes we now have 2 resources: `api` -> `api_key`, and `posts` -> array of posts, and `posts` resource cannot exist without the `api` resource because it's nested inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! There's so many conventions (which is great), but I'm still trying to wrap my head around what's created automatically along with best practices.